# Помогите разобраться со строками в с++

Tags: c++, строки

Суть задания состоит в том, что есть строка, и нужно вывести её, но слова в которых содержатся более 3х одинаковых букв вывести их '!'. причём допустим может быть 4 одинаковых буквы в этом слове и должно вывести "!!!!".
Например срока: abc abb aaa aaaabc
должно вывести : abc abb !!! !!!!;
мой код в онлайн компиляторе http://cpp.sh/93mdg

Comment: Поясните что не понятно.

Comment: Не понятно как сделать проверку на 3х букв и как это вывести

Answer (score 1):

Если я все правильно понял, то вот код

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int getMaxSameLetters(string s)
{
    map<char, int> freq;
    for (auto symb : s) {
        if (isalpha(symb)) {
            ++freq[symb];
        }
    }
    int maxSameLetters = 0;
    for (auto val : freq) {
        maxSameLetters = max(maxSameLetters, val.second);
    }
    return maxSameLetters;
}

string convertString(string s, int sameLetters)
{
    if (sameLetters < 3) {
        return s;
    }
    return string(sameLetters, '!');
}

int main()
{
    string text, tmp;

    getline(cin, text);
    for (auto symb : text) {
        if (isalpha(symb)) {
            tmp += symb;
        } else {
            cout << convertString(tmp, getMaxSameLetters(tmp)) << symb;
            tmp = "";
        }
    }
    cout << convertString(tmp, getMaxSameLetters(tmp)) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: спасибо) работает

Comment: Только передавайте строку в функцию через константную ссылку, а не по значению...

Answer (score 0):

это нужно делать через регулярные выражения.
Если не ошибаюсь, то вот такое: `(\w)\2+`

Comment: Приведите пример кода.